# Show custom node in outliner Editor Maya

Tags: python, pyside, maya, pymel

Is possible show custom nodes in clone outliner editor ?
I want showing custom groups and children meshes, from method and return to new outliner window.

I want create this manager, 4 columns is outliner

[image: This is manager]

Four columns outliner in layout:

```
      cmd.paneLayout('d', configuration='vertical4',  h=WS.h )
    cmd.formLayout('form_parts' )
        m = cmd.itemFilter( bs=partGroups() )
        editor = cmd.outlinerEditor( mainListConnection='worldList', selectionConnection='modelList',)
        outliner = cmd.outlinerEditor(editor, edit=True)
        cmd.setParent('..')
        cmd.formLayout('form_parts', edit=True, attachForm=[ (outliner, 'top', 0), (outliner, 'left', 0), (outliner, 'right', 0), (outliner, 'bottom', 0) ] )

cmd.formLayout('form_parts2')
    f = cmd.itemFilter(byType="transform")
    editor2 = cmd.outlinerEditor( mainListConnection='worldList', selectionConnection='modelList', filter = f )
    outliner2 = cmd.outlinerEditor(editor2, edit=True)
    cmd.setParent('..')
    cmd.formLayout('form_parts2', edit=True, attachForm=[ (outliner2, 'top', 0), (outliner2, 'left', 0), (outliner2, 'right', 0), (outliner2, 'bottom', 0) ] )

cmd.formLayout('form_parts3' )
    editor2 = cmd.outlinerEditor( mainListConnection='worldList', selectionConnection='modelList', f = "DefaultContainerFilter")
    outliner2 = cmd.outlinerEditor(editor2, edit=True)
    cmd.setParent('..')
    cmd.formLayout('form_parts3', edit=True, attachForm=[ (outliner2, 'top', 0), (outliner2, 'left', 0), (outliner2, 'right', 0), (outliner2, 'bottom', 0) ] )

cmd.formLayout('form_parts4' )
    editor3 = cmd.outlinerEditor( mainListConnection='worldList', selectionConnection='modelList', f = "DefaultContainerFilter" )
    outliner3 = cmd.outlinerEditor(editor3, edit=True)
    cmd.setParent('..')
    cmd.formLayout('form_parts4', edit=True, attachForm=[ (outliner3, 'top', 0), (outliner3, 'left', 0), (outliner3, 'right', 0), (outliner3, 'bottom', 0) ] )
```

My question is, or can only be, the content I need.
For example:

- First column only meshes
- Second column only groups and meshes tree
- Three column groups
- Four columns special groups define in method    and    return to
  content

**If this is not possible, I will probably have to write it pyside**

Thank you

Comment: what is clone outliner editor ? is it something from maya ?

Answer (score 0):

You  should user filter and setFilter .. please check this https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/outlinerEditor.html#flagsetFilter

For example

```
filterList = cmds.listNodeTypes("light")
cmds.outlinerEditor(myOutliner, edit=True, filter=filterMode, setFilter=filterMode, dag=False)
```